# Cupon opencart eeror

Tags: opencart

Good morning, by adding a discount coupon for all store customers, these customers can only use the same coupon once in their purchase, the coupon created by me is being used by the customer more than once, and in the administration of the store is marked only once per logged customer. How to fix this?

Comment: which opencart version?

Comment: if you need fast help. you can see my profiles and send msg to email or LinkedIn.
I am always ready to help peoples.